# Cakephp 3.0 taken data

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Hi I'm a novice in cakephp
However, I'm trying to make my blog with cakephp 3.0 which is stable version. I got stuck not taken database show view.ctp

#### Controller => "ListjobsController.php"

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
 class ListjobsController extends AppController{
    public function jobdetail(){
        $jobdetail = $this->Listjobs->find('all');
        $this->set( compact('jobdetail'));
    }
}
```

#### Model =>Table => "ListjobsTable.php"

```php
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ListjobsTable extends Table{
    public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->table('listjobs');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
         $this->belongsToMany('Users',[
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### Template => Listjobs => "jobdetail.ctp"

```php
<p><?= pr($jobdetail);exit; ?></p>
```

it does not appear that the current database information:

```
Cake\ORM\Query Object


(
[sql] => SELECT Listjobs.id AS `Listjobs__id`, Listjobs.user_id AS `Listjobs__user_id`, Listjobs.type_id AS `Listjobs__type_id`, Listjobs.cate_id AS `Listjobs__cate_id`, Listjobs.title AS `Listjobs__title`, Listjobs.location AS `Listjobs__location`, Listjobs.description AS `Listjobs__description`, Listjobs.skillsrequired AS `Listjobs__skillsrequired`, Listjobs.companyname AS `Listjobs__companyname`, Listjobs.website AS `Listjobs__website`, Listjobs.email AS `Listjobs__email`, Listjobs.password AS `Listjobs__password`, Listjobs.created AS `Listjobs__created`, Listjobs.modified AS `Listjobs__modified` FROM listjobs Listjobs
[params] => Array
    (
    )

[defaultTypes] => Array
    (
        [Listjobs.id] => integer
        [id] => integer
        [Listjobs.user_id] => integer
        [user_id] => integer
        [Listjobs.type_id] => integer
        [type_id] => integer
        [Listjobs.cate_id] => integer
        [cate_id] => integer
        [Listjobs.title] => string
        [title] => string
        [Listjobs.location] => string
        [location] => string
        [Listjobs.description] => text
        [description] => text
        [Listjobs.skillsrequired] => text
        [skillsrequired] => text
        [Listjobs.companyname] => string
        [companyname] => string
        [Listjobs.website] => string
        [website] => string
        [Listjobs.email] => string
        [email] => string
        [Listjobs.password] => string
        [password] => string
        [Listjobs.created] => datetime
        [created] => datetime
        [Listjobs.modified] => datetime
        [modified] => datetime
    )

[decorators] => 0
[executed] => 
[hydrate] => 1
[buffered] => 1
[formatters] => 0
[mapReducers] => 0
[contain] => Array
    (
    )

[matching] => Array
    (
    )

[extraOptions] => Array
    (
    )

[repository] => App\Model\Table\ListjobsTable Object
    (
        [registryAlias] => Listjobs
        [table] => listjobs
        [alias] => Listjobs
        [entityClass] => \Cake\ORM\Entity
        [associations] => Array
            (
                [0] => users
            )

        [behaviors] => Array
            (
            )

        [defaultConnection] => default
        [connectionName] => default
    )

)
```

I can not understand why the data in the database does not appear.
hope you can help me!!!

Comment: Did you create a Validation action in your `ListjobsTable`? If so, please post it here

Comment: thank you @AKKA-Web. I have found it.                                                that's because i print object not array

try this in controoler                                                                        $jobdetail = $this->Listjobs->find('all');
    $results = $jobdetail ->all();
    $data = $results->toArray();

Comment: For reference: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html** | **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data**

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` method always returns a `Query` object, that is the reason you cannot see the results but only the `SQL` that is going to be executed. If you are just starting with cake 3 there are a couple nice way in which you can see what the results of a query are:

```
debug($this->Table->find('all')->toArray());
```

That will give you an array of entities that were fetched from the database, the output may still be a bit confusing for you if you are not use to the idea of entities. SO here is another trick:

```
// In bootstrap.php
function dj($data)
{
     debug(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

And then:

```
dj($this->Table->find('all'));
```

Answer (score 0):

do change in controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

class ListjobsController extends AppController{

  public function jobdetail(){

      $jobdetail = $this->Listjobs->find('all');
      $this->set('listjobs', $jobdetail);
      $this->set('_serialize', ['listjobs']);
  }
}
```

now you can display data at view

Answer (score -1):

Write in the `appController.php` file:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadModel('Listjobs');
}
```

This should solve your problem.